# Twitter Gallery Cards deprecated

Tags: image, twitter, share, twitter-card

I programmed a web page that share web contents via Facebook, Pinterest and Twitter,
but I check that using Twitter is not possible to share web contents like for example
photos, it can be do it easily with URLs but I think that is more interesting share a photo
than a URLs because an image is more visual and friendly as a marketing strategy, for this i want to 
use Twitter Card Gallery but is currently deprecated, nowadays Twitter uses a new card called:Summary Card with Large Image

**Example (extracted from Twitter documentation):**

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@nytimes">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@SarahMaslinNir">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Parade of Fans for Houston’s Funeral">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="NEWARK - The guest list and parade of 
            limousines with celebrities emerging from them seemed more suited to a 
            red carpet event in Hollywood or New York than than a gritty stretch
            of Sussex Avenue near the former site of the James M. Baxter Terrace public housing project here.">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2012/02/19/us/19whitney-span/19whitney-span-articleLarge.jpg">
```

**The question is:** Somebody knows what is the proper way to share images on Twitter?, for example, the images published on a gallery.

Answer (score 1):

[Deprecating the Photo, Gallery and Product Cards](https://twittercommunity.com/t/deprecating-the-photo-gallery-and-product-cards/38961)

Twitter Cards enable you to richly represent your content on Twitter and help drive engagement. Over the years we’ve added new Card types158, made performance improvements, simplified whitelisting and have a lot more planned for the platform in the future. To make the most of those opportunities, however, we need to focus.

Today, we're announcing that we're retiring the Photo, Gallery, and Product Cards. These Cards represent just a small percentage of the total Cards shared on Twitter and we want to pour resources into the ones that are making an impact and into new ideas and products on the horizon. Changes like this are never easy, but we’re committed to building great products for our publishers and users.